# NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RelativeLayout.addView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, paypal, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to implement PayPal functionality in an app.  In order to get it working, I'm trying to create a simple app that only shows the PayPal button that, once pressed, will pass all of the necessary parameters to the library to take the user through the log-in and payment process.

When I run this code, I get the following error message:

> 03-11 20:48:05.588 23566-23566/org.kevinbright.android.paypaldemo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                       Process: org.kevinbright.android.paypaldemo, PID: 23566
>                                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.kevinbright.android.paypaldemo/org.kevinbright.android.paypaldemo.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RelativeLayout.addView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference

The error relates to this section:

```
((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout01)).
            addView(launchPayPalButton);
```

Here's the code:

```
 package org.kevinbright.android.paypaldemo;

public class MainActivity extends Activity   {

    private CheckoutButton launchPayPalButton;
    final static public int PAYPAL_BUTTON_ID = 10001;
    private static final int REQUEST_PAYPAL_CHECKOUT = 2;
    private double _theSubtotal;
    private double _taxAmount;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        initLibrary();
        showPayPalButton();

    }

    private void showPayPalButton() {
        //LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        //linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        //ViewGroup.LayoutParams linearLayoutParam = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        //setContentView(linearLayout, linearLayoutParam);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        params.bottomMargin = 10;

        // Generate the PayPal checkout button and save it for later use
        PayPal pp = PayPal.getInstance();
        launchPayPalButton = pp.getCheckoutButton(this, PayPal.BUTTON_194x37, CheckoutButton.TEXT_PAY);

        // The OnClick listener for the checkout button
        launchPayPalButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                payPalButtonClick(arg0);
            }
        });

        // Add the listener to the layout
        launchPayPalButton.setLayoutParams(params);
        launchPayPalButton.setId(PAYPAL_BUTTON_ID);
        ((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout01)).
                addView(launchPayPalButton);

    }

    public void payPalButtonClick(View arg0) {
        PayPalPayment newPayment = new PayPalPayment();
        newPayment.setSubtotal(new BigDecimal(_theSubtotal));
        newPayment.setCurrencyType("USD");
        newPayment.setRecipient("my@email.com");
        newPayment.setMerchantName("My Company");
        Intent checkoutIntent = PayPal.getInstance().checkout(newPayment, this);
        startActivityForResult(checkoutIntent, REQUEST_PAYPAL_CHECKOUT);


    }



    public void initLibrary() {
        PayPal pp = PayPal.getInstance();

        if (pp == null) {  // Test to see if the library is already initialized

            // This main initialization call takes your Context, AppID, and target server
            pp = PayPal.initWithAppID(this, "APP-80W284485P519543T", PayPal.ENV_NONE);

            // Required settings:

            // Set the language for the library
            pp.setLanguage("en_US");

            // Some Optional settings:

            // Sets who pays any transaction fees. Possible values are:
            // FEEPAYER_SENDER, FEEPAYER_PRIMARYRECEIVER, FEEPAYER_EACHRECEIVER, and FEEPAYER_SECONDARYONLY
            pp.setFeesPayer(PayPal.FEEPAYER_EACHRECEIVER);

            // true = transaction requires shipping
            pp.setShippingEnabled(false);
        }

    }

}
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error message, since `launchPayPalButton` references `pp`, which is an object of the `PayPal Class` that is initialized in the `initLibrary` method before `showPayPalButton` is called.

Please help!!!

Edit:  This is not a duplicate of the questions referenced.  I have reviewed that post and that post is about referening objects that have not been initialized and thus, return a null reference.  This question explains why this should not generate a null pointer exception because the object is initialized.

Edit 2:  Here's my .xml file called "customize.xml" that saved in the Layouts folder under "Res."

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                >
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Yes, I've reviewed that post, and I've explained why I don't believe (or understand why) it is a null pointer exception.

Comment: `(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout01)` is returning null. Are you sure `R.id.RelativeLayout01` is the id of an accessible view when it is being called?

Comment: he never set the view to Activity, so obviously any findViewById call will return null

Comment: How to debug a null pointer is asked dozens of times per day.  You need to learn how to debug one on your own, its pretty much debugging 101.  Now if you find a function returning null that you think shouldn't be, or a variable becoming null when it shouldn't, then you may have a question.  Until then these questions are all going to be closed as dupes, you aren't doing your share of the research.

Comment: The problem was not anything to do with 'launchPayPalButton'.  Instead, the problem was with 'addView' since I forget to set the view via 'setContentView' in 'onCreare'.